# Cannot Maintain Session on Page Refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, redux

I have an app built with Rails, React, and Webpacker.  I'm using token based authentication, so when a user creates an account or signs in they are assigned a token in the DB.  This token is then used to access the user's profile.  The profile page loads without issue after the user authenticates, but I get a Rails error saying `Couldn't find Registration` and it then references this line from my registration_controller: `registration = Registration.find_by_auth_token!(request.headers[:token])`.

I've tried setting the token within localStorage when it's received from the backend, and I've tried calling the token from localStorage when the page loads on the top level components using the `useEffect` hook, but it doesn't seem like my React app even starts to render before I get this error page.  None of the Console.log statements I've added to my React app appear in the console when I get this error.

registration_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index; end

  def custom
    user = Registration.create!(registration_params)
    render json: { token: user.auth_token, id: user.id }
  end

  def profile

    registration = Registration.find_by_auth_token!(request.headers[:token])
    render json: {
      registration: { username: registration.username, email: registration.email, name: registration.name }
    }
  end

  private

  def registration_params
    params.require(:registration).permit(:username, :email, :password, :name)
  end
end
```

auth.js (actions)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import reduxStore from '../reduxStore';

export const LOGOUT_START = 'auth/logoutStart';
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESSFUL = 'auth/logoutSuccessful';
export const LOGOUT_ERROR = 'auth/logoutError';
export const LOGIN_START = 'auth/loginStart';
export const LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL = 'auth/loginSuccessful';
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'auth/loginFailure';
export const REGISTRATION_START = 'auth/registrationStart';
export const REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL = 'auth/registrationSuccessful';
export const REGISTRATION_FAILURE = 'auth/registrationFailure';

export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
  const headers = { token: localStorage.token };
  // console.log('redux store', reduxStore().getState())
  // console.log('NEW local storage', localStorage);
  dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_START });

  try {
    axios.delete('/logout', { headers })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGOUT_SUCCESSFUL,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`logout error: ${e}`);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGOUT_ERROR,
      payload: e,
    });
  }
};

export const login = ({ username, password }) => (dispatch) => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  const data = {
    username,
    password,
  };

  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_START });

  try {
    axios.post('/login', data, { headers })
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL,
          payload: res.data,
        });
        // localStorage.setItem('myValueInLocalStorage', event.target.value)
        console.log('localStorage', localStorage);
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`login error ${e}`);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
      payload: e,
    });
  }
};

export const createUser = ({
  username,
  password,
  name,
  email,
}) => (dispatch) => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

  const data = {
    registration: {
      username,
      password,
      name,
      email,
    },
  };

  dispatch({ type: REGISTRATION_START });

  try {
    axios.post('/registration/custom', data, { headers })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL,
          payload: res.data,
        });
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`createUser error: ${e}`);
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTRATION_FAILURE,
      payload: e,
    });
  }
};
```

I'd expect this token to always be available from the Headers in the Request object on the Rails side so the profile page can be shown when a user refreshes the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding some helper functions and changing some logic on the React side.  I started setting/getting/clearing the token in localStorage when the page loads, when a user signs in, and when a user signs out, and this ended up being a better way to manage the authenticated state on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

If your header is "token", rails will convert that to "HTTP_TOKEN", run `puts request.headers.inspect` to see what's actually inside that headers object, I think you have to use a string and not a symbol too (headers['HTTP_TOKEN'] instead of headers[:http_token])

Comment: I checked this and I don't see HTTP_TOKEN in the `request.headers` object.  I feel like the issue could be that the token is sent in a Redux request, but Rails is loading before Rails/React so that request with the token is never being sent from React to Rails?

Comment: Do you have this running online on a webserver? if so, nginx by default expects custom  headers to be called "X-Something". I don't understand what you mean that the request is not sent, you can check the browser's dev tools and the rails server log to confirm being sent and being received.

Comment: This isn't deployed, it's running locally.  What I meant was the Rails controller method was being hit before the React app loaded, so it's not receiving a token header.  If Rails waits for React to load before hitting the controller method, React would be able to send the token to Rails for the method to then use and load the appropriate user.